# An interesting function. Is it convex, quasi-convex, or pseudo-convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

The function is described as follows:

[image]

I have found that it is not convex when N>=3, and I feel that it shall be pseudo-convex. Can anyone help to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: What sets do $\mathbf{R}^{N-1}_{++}$ and $\mathbf{R}^{N \times N}_{+}$ denote?

Comment: At a glance looks like a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Definitions), but I wonder if $W$ doesn't qualify.

Comment: I like this question, but it may be better suited for the math SE community. It appears to be purely math with no clear connection to statistics or machine learning.